# Twitter header picture

Tags: images, resize

I have an almost square picture which I want to upload as Twitter header photo without it being "zoomed in" or losing the background. Ideally i would like to keep the picture without losing anything. Is it possible to keep the original with maybe white sides as Twitter header is more of a landscape shape?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the header banner 1500px by 500px if you do not want twitter to scale your graphic to cover the banner. So in whichever graphics editing program you use, make a document that size and place your square image inside the document and scale accordingly.